# Integrating fraction with two square roots in denominator

Tags: integration, analysis

I have a trouble with solving

$$
\int \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{1+x}}
$$

This can probably be solved by some form of substitution, but it didn't lead me to some clear enading or further steps.

Comment: You could try to see what happens if you multiply top and bottom by $(1+ \sqrt{x})-\sqrt{1+x}$.

Comment: Do you mean rationalisation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{1+x}}&=\frac{1+\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1+x}}{(1+\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1+x})(1+\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1+x})}\\
&=\frac{1+\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{1+x}}{2\,\sqrt x}
\end{align}$$

Comment: lol. You beat me to it.

Comment: This hint was already given by @randomgirl in the comment ;)

Comment: This can be simply rewrited into $\frac{1}{2}\left(\int 1 dx + \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx - \int \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{x}} dx \right)$

Comment: Ooooh... there comes the substitution: $u = \sqrt{x}$ (therefore $du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{1+x}} = \frac{1 -( \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{1+x})}{(1 + \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{1+x})(1 -( \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{1+x}))}$$
You will end up with one root in the denominator. Do this trick again to end up with only a polynomial of degree 1 in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

1. Getting rid of the $\sqrt{x}$. Chage variable $x=t^2$. The $\sqrt{1+x}$ turns into $\sqrt{1+t^2}$.
2. Getting rid of the $\sqrt{1+t^2}$. Use Euler substitution.

These steps work for any function $R(x,\sqrt{x},\sqrt{1+x})$, where $R$ is a rational function.